# Extract dynamic union from javascript object that is already typed

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to dynamically create a union type based on some properties from a javascript object.
Unfortunately the object is already typed to enforce conventions..

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:
[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAghCAlA9gVxFAzgYRQOwDMBLAcxgF4YBvYGGAJxRRAC4a76YBHNKBsAAUAhg2EBbLO1pcuWEKJBSY8hsXylOsiMNJR2+NOIBG-LTAC+nK-XFQT-aed78hoicpmyYOvQaOmDOY2lpxYUCAg6qSe5jogABYiYpJO3jDEACbsqtHB1sBWoJCweERkACollBz0ANoA1lBgGfgwTWAohPCIqBjYZSSkALppXPEJOSBqGgVFAMYE8ozomMqDldVUXkws0j7CiewA5MeWADScdg4M+xMnAPTXgWcWl-ThkdGeB0cwxw9PlENFhXoUYMIsDBFvh5MBgA8HjAAJIwADuwnwIBgIkSAFV8MQCDAQCgYFBeMIADZSBFI8DQHGHBIEoltKinGAAH3+T3sL25vKB32OdOKjNxLMJxKoDKgXRW-SwjWaCrlCqYSuGdWOE2OwyAA)

```js
type AppRoutesConfig = {
  root: {
    queryParams: {
      starts: string
      page: number
    }
  }
  member: {
    queryParams: {
      page: number
    }
  }
  settings: {
    pathParams: {
      id: string
    }
  }
}

type ConfigType = {
  [key in keyof AppRoutesConfig]: {
    path: string
  }
}

const routes: ConfigType = {
  root: { path: '' },
  member: { path: '/member' },
  settings: { path: '/settings' }
} as const

// I want PathUnion to equals:
// type PathUnion = '' | '/member' | '/settings'
type PathUnion = typeof routes[keyof typeof routes]['path']
```

Comment: (If you remove `: ConfigType` and keep `as const` that would prevent you/developers from adding/changing any entries ever)

Comment: The thing is I want to keep `ConfigType`

Comment: `ConfigType` as an annotation will and cannot be prevented from ruining your union type. You are cutting off your nose to spite your face and I don't know why

Comment: @AluanHaddad - `ConfigType` just help me ton keep types config and js config in sync, so new devs that adds an entry in the js config have to also add types - maybe I should find an alternative

Comment: Yes but don't use it on that variable. It simply won't work because it erases all the types of all the values

Comment: @AluanHaddad is there a way to let the `path` property a dynamic type ?

Comment: No. When you use a type annotation, that's the type you end up with. And it isn't Dynamic typing that were talking about it is type inference. The difference is important because, the more imprecise type annotations you have, and precise type annotations for objects like that are extraordinarily verbose with many generics, you the less static typing you end up with.

Comment: Remember, typescript is about having types not about writing types